# Retrieve list of due dates for Google Classroom

Tags: api, google-signin, google-classroom

I'm new to both programming and Google Classroom API. My current goal is to be able to retrieve a list of dates for the coursework. I managed to enable Google Sign In through Firebase, but I'm not sure what to do next with the Classroom API.

So far, I created a swift file to manage the API.
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

class MainPgViewController: UIViewController {
var classroomAPI = ClassroomAPIManager()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

```
Here's my code for Google Sign In (App Delegate):
```

import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseAuth

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()
    return true
    
}
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}



func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {

    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {

    
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
}


func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
  // ...
    if error != nil {
    return
  }

  guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    _ = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
        accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

}
```

}

}

````
For the view controller (Login):
```import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate{
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveMain", sender: self)
    }
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    }
````

Thank you in advance!

Nobel

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and [**don't** just include a link to a code hosting site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/316262). Your post should stand alone from any other resource; [consider what would happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) if that site went down in the future!

Comment: Could you please provide the code you're working on? If I understand you correctly, you want to retrieve the list of `dueDates` for the courseWork from a certain course? Have you gone through the authorization process already?

Comment: Yeah sure. I've edited my post to include the code. Feel free to ask me if you need more code. Yes, I do want to obtain the list of ```dueDates```, as well as the corresponding name of the courseWork. To my knowledge, I have gone through the authorization process already. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I guess you want to retrieve the list of `dueDates` for the different `courseWork` in a specific `course`? Also, if you want others to receive a notification when you comment something, please add `@` to the user's name, like @Iamblichus